# $\log(n+1) = 1 + 4/3\log(c(n+1))$ solve for c

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\log(n+1) = 1 + 4/3\log(c(n+1))$$

how do I solve for c so that this equation holds?

$$\log(n+1) = 1 + \log(c(n+1)) = 1 + 4/3\log(c) + 4/3\log(n+1)$$

now what?

Comment: Write this as $\log(c)=\dots$ and then apply the exponential function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\log(n+1)= 1 + \frac{4}{3}\log c + \frac{4}{3} \log(n+1)$$ 
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$1-\frac{1}{3}\log(n+1) = -\frac{4}{3}\log c $$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$3 - \log(n+1) = -4\log c$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$4\log(n+1) -12 = \log c$$
$$c = e^{4\log(n+1)-12}$$

The final expression can be further simplified.